# Android client socket. UnknowHostException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have a working server application in JAVA (multithreaded) and a working client console application.

Now I'm trying to do an android client, however using Eclipse and the Android emulator I can't connect to my local server ....

- yes, I use 10.0.2.2 as my server ip.
- yes, Manifest file is modified with INTERNET permission.

  ```
          import java.io.BufferedReader;
          import java.io.BufferedWriter;
          import java.io.IOException;
          import java.io.InputStreamReader;
          import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
          import java.io.PrintWriter;
          import java.net.Socket;
          import java.net.UnknownHostException;

          import android.app.Activity;
          import android.os.Bundle;
          import android.view.View;
          import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
          import android.widget.Button;
          import android.widget.ImageButton;
          import android.widget.TextView;
          import android.widget.Toast;

          public class RealApp extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

              private PrintWriter pw;
              private BufferedReader in;
              private boolean connected = false;

              public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
              {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.main);

                  if (!connected) 
                  {
                      Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                      cThread.start();
                  }


              }



              public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

                  public void run() {

                      {

                          Socket skt = null;
                          try {
                              skt = new Socket("l0.0.2.2", 1337);
                          } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e1.printStackTrace();
                          } catch (IOException e1) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e1.printStackTrace();
                          }

                          String s = "";
                          String inString = "";

                          BufferedReader in = null;
                          try {
                              in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
                          } catch (IOException e2) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e2.printStackTrace();
                          }
                          PrintWriter pw = null;
                          try {
                              pw = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
                          } catch (IOException e1) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e1.printStackTrace();
                          }


                          do
                          {
                              try {
                                  inString = in.readLine();
                              } catch (IOException e) {
                                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              }


                          }
                          while(!s.equals("quit"));


                          pw.close();
                          try {
                              skt.close();
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }



                      }
                  }
              }}
  ```

During a debug, in the Log window I can notice a System.err message, an UnknowHostException for 10.0.2.2.

Comment: You didn't specify what you are testing on, but keep in mind the 10.0.2.2 alias only works with an emulator, and not with an actual phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try [creating an InetAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) and using the [Socket constructor which takes an InetAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29), this should avoid the lookup.